# LaTeX formulas to images conversion in Jekyll.rb

Tags: ruby, latex, jekyll, maruku

I'm creating a site using jekyll.rb.

When converting LaTeX equations to PNG images using Blahtex, Maruku stores the images in the "latex/images" directory. I have to manually copy this directory to "_site" directory for the equations to be displayed correctly. Is this normal behavior?

Here is my _config.yml file.

```
url: "http://localhost:4000"

paginate: 10

source:      .
destination: ./_site

markdown: maruku
pygments: true

maruku:
    use_tex : true
    use_divs : true
    png_engine : blahtex
    png_dir : images/latex/
    png_url : /images/latex/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/). MathJax is an open source JavaScript display engine for mathematics that works in all browsers.

Comment: Many LaTeX features are not part of MathJax, so this answer only applies if you are trying to display equations rather than, say, an example of how a document is formatted.